# Chrome debugger variable value on hover

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

This bug is back for me.  On breakpoint local variables Chrome debugger is no longer displaying the values on hover.  This used to work fine.

Anyone else seeing this?

Chrome version:
Chrome is up to date
Version 99.0.4844.51 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: its also not working in latest Version 105.0.5195.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, using Chrome 105.0.5195.127
This defect had been seen in 2019 and sadly it comes back again.

Comment: Weirdly enough, it works in one file for me, and fails in a different file. I haven't yet found the cause, still investigating.  Not sure that it came with a update. My version is 107.0.5304.88